# Thread was being aborted. Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sime code like this

```
  Response.Redirect(sUrl,true);
```

which I want to execution of the page terminated , but it gives me the error

> Thread was being aborted.
> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

I don't want to add the false for the second paramter which mean the execution of page continues.
and if I set it to

```
Response.Redirect(sUrl,false);
```

not matters I get the same error again
how should I resove the problem?